# how to check json key(object) is exist?

Tags: android, json

I want to put validation for check key is exist or not.

```
{
 "id":"ProbaRegatta",
 "name":"Congo",
 "email":"invited"
 }
```

And sometimes, there will be an extra field like:

```
  {
   "id":"ProbaRegatta",
   "name":"Congo",
   "email":"invited"
   "contact":"xxxx"
   }
```

so i would to check 'contact' key exist

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
boolean check = obj.has("name");
```

Comment: Please try to add details about the answer as possible - From Review

Comment: thanks , its work in my project...

Comment: you are welcome @Divyesh

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in below code

```
/**
 * Check the Existance of Given String in given JSONObject
 */

public static boolean hasData(JSONObject jsonObject, String string) {
    return jsonObject.has(string) && !jsonObject.isNull(string);
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method `jsonObject.has("key")` for checking key is exit or not, and `jsonObject.isNull("key")` for null value.